# How to set all values to false in array?

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

I have a code like this:

```
$iterator = 0;
while (($end = $sth->fetch()) && $iterator < 2)
{
    $api_arr["data"]['tc'][] =  $end["tc"];
    $api_arr["data"]['em'][] =  $end["em"];
    $api_arr["data"]['sg'][] =  $end["sg"];

    $iterator ++;
}
```

I'm creating a API of my website for other developers. I give them a JSON output. Something like this:

```
{
   -data{
       tc: [
         "value_tc_1",
         "value_tc_2",
         "value_tc_3" 
       ],

       em: [
         "value_em_1",
         "value_em_2",
         "value_em_3" 
       ],

       sg: [
         "value_sg_1",
         "value_sg_2",
         "value_sg_3" 
       ]
   }
}
```

---

**Current output:** *(when there isn't any rows `$sth->rowCount() == ''`)*

```
[]
```

**What I want:** *(when there isn't any rows `$sth->rowCount() == ''`)*

```
{
   -data{
       tc: [false],
       em: [false],
       sg: [false]
   }
}
```

Well, How can I do that?

---

**As a consultation:** is it necessarily to set `false` as array's values when there is no result? I've never had the experience of creating an API. I want to set `false` according to some similar APIs *(from other websites)*.

Actually I want to present a standard and usable to the other developers. So, what I do is right as a API? Other developers will be able to use it?

I don't know, maybe what I need is this:

```
{
   -data{
       tc: false,
       em: false,
       sg: false
   }
}
```

Generally is there any point that I need to know? {Beforehand thanks `:)`}

---

**What I tried:** I think something like this will be useful, But actually I don't know how should I use it:

```
array_fill_keys(array_keys($api_arr['data']), "false");
```

Comment: You'd be better off sending a no data, maybe a 404 response, rather than the array with false values.

Comment: 1) You can figure out how many iterations of your loop you've done, so if you didn't do any, add one round of `false` to it. 2) That is a weird data structure. An *array* is a container to hold many things. If there are no things it should hold, it should simply be empty. Having it hold one thing of type `false` to signify that it's empty is bizarre.

Comment: You could also return an error object, that says no data found and a status code.

Comment: Are you developing a REST API? Then you will find the answer to some of your questions in the documentation (description) of the REST protocol.
If you are not developing a REST API, then you should talk with the developers implementing the client part how this data structure should look like.

Comment: @deceze *"That is a weird data structure."*, Well what you said is exactly what I need to hear.. So how should I show the data which be fine? This is better `$api_arr["data"][]['tc'] =  $end["tc"];`

Comment: use `foreach`-Loop and unset the entries with `unset()`, that should do it for you

Comment: @deceze still waiting for your opinion about my data-structure ..! at least give me [a number](http://imgur.com/BDwwtCV)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initiate the array with empty values:

```
$iterator = 0;
$api_arr = [
    'data'=>
        [
            'tc'=>[],
            'em'=>[],
            'sg'=>[]
        ]
    ];

while (($end = $sth->fetch()) && $iterator < 2)
{
    $api_arr["data"]['tc'][] =  $end["tc"];
    $api_arr["data"]['em'][] =  $end["em"];
    $api_arr["data"]['sg'][] =  $end["sg"];

    $iterator ++;
}
```

If there is no results in the database, the result will be:

```
{
   data{
       tc: [],
       em: [],
       sg: []
   }
}
```

Which will be consistent for API consumers who expect a data structure containing arrays. Probably the whole structure can be refactored, but consistency is a good start

To expand on `"the whole structure can be refactored"`part, looking at the data, it seems that the values are logically grouped in the database (a row contains related `tc`, `em` and `sg` cells), yet you seperate them in the API for no clear reason.

A better structure would be to follow the structure of the database:

```
$iterator = 0;
$data = [];
while (($end = $sth->fetch()) && $iterator < 2)
{
    $data[] =  [
        'tc'=> $end["tc"],
        'em'=> $end["em"],
        'sg'=> $end["sg"]
   ];
    $iterator ++;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode([data=>$data]);
```

This will output:

```
{
    data:[
       {tc: value_tc_1, em: value_em_1, sg: value_sg_1},
       {tc: value_tc_2, em: value_em_2, sg: value_sg_2},
       {tc: value_tc_3, em: value_em_3, sg: value_sg_3}
    ]
}
```

When you have results, and:

```
{
    data:[]
}
```

When no results.

The consumers code can be for example (using php again, could be any language):

```
 $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($apiEndpoint));
 foreach($response->data as $element){
     echo '<tr><td>' . $element->tc . '</td><td>' . $element->em . '</td><td>' . $element->sg . '<td></tr>';
 }
```

And no matter whether your api returns results or not, the consumer code runs fine (just showing an empty table if there are no results).

As a final note, if your SQL is more specific in what you want, eg:

```
SELECT tc, em, sg FROM tablename LIMIT 3
```

Then your whole php code becomes:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode([data=>$sth->fetchAll()]);
```

No need for iterator, while loop etc

Comment: Thanks, But if I want to keep `null` the values when there is no result, I can just use `do-while()` instead of what you wrote ...

Comment: This comes down to API design, not any specific programming language. However, an api that returns an array of values, would normally be expected to return an empty array if there are none. returning array or false is inconsistent and requires the consumer to add guard clauses to all there code.

Comment: Ah ok, just one thing: the data structure is fine? They are usable for other developers or even a mobile-app?

Comment: Well the 1st one is closer to what i would recomend, but ist still a bit broken. you dont want `data:{ 0:{}, 1:{}, ...}` you want `data:[{},{}, ...]` Im not even sure how you managed to get that output in the 1st place, `json_encode` should translate a sequential, numerically indexed array into an array, not an object

Comment: The reason its important is because an array can be iterated in pretty much any language with a simple loop, but an object is much harder to traverse.

Comment: Ow, good point ...! you know what is my problem? that's old-php-version. Because it doesn't support this `$arr = [];` *(**Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected '[' in {address})*, And I have to write that like this `$arr = array();`. So I don't know how should I exactly write my code for getting this `data:[{},{}, ...]`

Comment: Here is my current code: `$api_arr["data"][] = array("tc" => $end["tc"], ...);`. How change it?

Comment: That should be fine - how do you convert to json?

Comment: [My main question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34273845/which-kind-of-data-structure-is-more-better). If you have some free time please take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Returning an error object keeps consistency and is easily to catch in the client side:

Say you return this if no data is found:

```
$api_arr["error"]["code"] = 404;
$api_arr["error"]["message"] = "No data found";
```

Now in the client side, in an ajax request someone could easily do this:

```
try {
   if(typeof ajaxObj.error != 'undefined'){
        throw ajaxObj.error;
   }

   //Data is found
} catch(errObj) {
   //Handle the error object.
}
```

Comment: Do you mean I return nothing *(even `null`)* when there isn't found any result ?

Comment: @stack exactly don't return an data object at all.

Comment: Ok, seems good +1, But one thing, the data structure is ok? is it standard? people can use it in the client side? or should I show them some pattern else?

Comment: This is perfectly fine, I've seen it in applications. However I would advice to create documentation for other developers, so they know they can either expect an error or an data object.

Comment: Very good, and for the last time, [this](http://imgur.com/z8UPX5S) is fine? A developer can use it as client side? or can I use if for example in the android-app?

Comment: Yes it's fine, and it will work in an android app aswell as a client-side request.

Comment: Well, really sorry for asking again, but may please tell me [which data-strucure](http://imgur.com/BDwwtCV) is more better as a API?