# Which kind of data structure is better?

Tags: php, android, arrays, data-structures

I'm creating an API for my website. That API will be used by other developers or an Android application. Well, I have two kind of data structures:

**One:**

```
$iterator = 0;
while (($end = $sth->fetch()) && $iterator < 2)
{
    $api_arr["data"][] =  array(
        "id"      =>  $end["id"],
        "title"   =>  $end["title"],
        "content" =>  $end["content"] );   
$iterator ++;
}


/* Output: ------------ print_r($api_arr); -------------------

Array
(
   [data] => Array
      (
        [0] =>
          (
            [id]      => value_id_1
            [title]   => value_title_1
            [content] => value_content_1
          )

        [1] =>
          (
            [id]      => value_id_2
            [title]   => value_title_2
            [content] => value_content_2
          )
      )
) */


/* Output: ------------ echo json_encode($data); -------------------
             ----- and using JSONveiw extension on chrome -----

{
   - data: {
       - 0: {
           id: "value_id_1",
           title: "value_title_1",
           content: "value_content_1"
         },

       - 1: {
           id: "value_id_2",
           title: "value_title_2",
           content: "value_content_2"
         },
    }
} */
```

**Two:**

```
$iterator = 0;
while (($end = $sth->fetch()) && $iterator < 2)
{
    $api_arr["data"]['id'][]       =  $end["id"];
    $api_arr["data"]['title'][]    =  $end["title"];
    $api_arr["data"]['content'][]  =  $end["content"];
$iterator ++;
}


/* Output: ------------ print_r($api_arr); -------------------

Array
(
  [data] =>
     (
        [id] => Array
           (
               [0] => value_id_1
               [1] => value_id_2
               [2] => value_id_3
           ),

        [title] => Array
           (
               [0] => value_title_1
               [1] => value_title_2
               [2] => value_title_3
           ),

        [content] => Array
           (
               [0] => value_content_1
               [1] => value_content_2
               [2] => value_content_3
           )
      )
) */

/* Output: ------------ echo json_encode($data); -------------------
             ----- and using JSONveiw extension on chrome -----

{
   - data: {
        - id:[
               "value_id_1",
               "value_id_2",
               "value_id_3
             ],
        - title:[
               "value_title_1,
               "value_title_2,
               "value_title_3,
             ],
        - content:[
               "value_content_1",
               "value_content_2",
               "value_content_3
             ],
     }
} */
```

So, Which data-structure is better for using it in client side? *(other websites, mobile-app)*

Comment: As per my comments previously, and the current answer below, the 1st structure is preferable **if** you were creating an array, not an object with numerical properties. I honestly dont know how you could even get that output from the provided code

Comment: Perhaps you should show the full code including where you create the json

Comment: neither. the second one is horrible, and the keys in the first one are useless

Comment: @Steve I get that output like this: https://3v4l.org/AeFFr . Please fix it and remove that keys which are useless.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the array generating code: https://3v4l.org/a7jXS So you must be doing something odd to create that json

Comment: @Steve lemme ask something, JSONveiw extension is install on your browser?

Comment: Nope, i lust look at the actual raw json string - you can see it in the link i provided above. Maybe that plugin is broken?

Comment: @Steve Well, I executed that link which you provided on my own laptop and the output was different with the output of 3v4l.org. So all my problem is just that plugin..! Because my code is completely correct. Anyway thanks, you have devoted plenty of time to me today .. `:-)` !! (btw Stack is my friend and he is next to me)

Comment: Ha, no problem, glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first one you are simulating the use of an array without actually using an array (or at least it looks like given your output), and in the second one you are repeating info and forcing the developer to put it all together. The best solution is:

```
{
    data: [
        {
            id: "",
            title: "",
            content: ""
        },
        {
            id: "",
            title: "",
            content: ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I think this is pretty similar to your first option, but looks like the plugin is showing it in a bad way or something.

The main reason why Android devs prefer that is because a direct translation between objects and json can be done with some libraries.

Comment: Well thanks, but how can I generate this output? May you please add some code to your answer?

Comment: Sorry I have no expertise on php so probably my code will not be correct, but you can create a small service and make some tests accessing to it with the chrome browser or postman if you have to do a POST operation